# Time Zone Picker In XPages?

Tags: xpages

When adding a field to a form in Lotus Notes, one of the possible types is that of "Time Zone". When viewed in the Notes client, it is similar in appearance to a combo box where one of the choices looks like this:
    (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

When selected, it displays like this:
    GMT+01:00

And when saved, it's stored like this:
    "Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZX=103$ZN=W. Europe"

I'm creating an XPage front-end for the Resource form in a modified Resource Reservation template, so I need a control like this in XPages, but don't see one. How do I get/create a control like a Time Zone field?

Comment: I don't remember where I got it but I used a ZULU timezone picker based on jQuery to perform an operation like this - and it stored the data in the format you are describing. Try searching for "zulu timezone picker jquery". Sorry for not having a working solution yet...

Comment: Thanks, but the only things I could find either first drills down to a country or uses an image map. While that is certainly useful, it won't help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've seen this OpenNTF Project for [Resource Reservations Extended](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/ResX%20-%20Resource%20Reservations%20Extended), but it may give an idea (bear in mind the code gets very deep in Java). The selection and display do what you need in a combo box, the save then converts and stores the timezone in Notes format.

Comment: I had not seen the Project until now. It's pretty involved, but I think I can get out of it what I need.